# Understand AVFoundation videoOrientation and Vision Request Handler Orientation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, vision, visionkit

I'm try to understand what I'm doing wrong on my project.
I'm try to draw a box over a detected face using vision kit.

I first set up the back camera with the following method.

```
 func configureSession(){
        // controllo se ho ricevuto auth a usar camera else ret
        if setupResult != .success { return }
        var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
        session.beginConfiguration() // per poter sett la conf
        session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480 // Model image size is smaller.
        do {
            
            // seleziono il device migliore da usare come imput
            if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,for: .video,position: .back) {
                print("select input tripleCamera")
                defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
            }

            guard let defaultVideoDevice = defaultVideoDevice else {
                print("errore Can not find any camera in configurate session")
                return
            }
            let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice)
            
            //Aggiungo input alla sessione
            if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput){
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

            } else {
                print("Could not add video device input to the session")
                setupResult = .configurationFailed
                session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }// fine add input
        } catch let error {
            print("Could set input device to session err \(error.localizedDescription)")
            setupResult = .configurationFailed
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }
        
        //-----aggiungi Output
        if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
            session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            // Add a video data output
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)
            
        }else {
            print("Could not add video data output to the session")
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }
        
        guard let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video) else {return}
        captureConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait  //< DO I NEED TO CHANGE THIS??----------
        captureConnection.isEnabled = true
        if captureConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
            print("capture connection orient \(captureConnection.videoOrientation.rawValue) / 3 landscape right")
        }
        // get the buffer size
        do {
            try  defaultVideoDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
            let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions((defaultVideoDevice?.activeFormat.formatDescription)!)
            bufferSize.width = CGFloat(dimensions.width)
            bufferSize.height = CGFloat(dimensions.height)
            defaultVideoDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("// get the buffer size ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        cameraView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        // setting up the view to show
        cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        
        session.commitConfiguration()
        cameraView.session = session
        rootLayer = cameraView.videoPreviewLayer
        guard let conn = self.cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.connection else {return}
        
        print("cameraView conn video orient \(conn.videoOrientation.rawValue)")
    }
```

First question..
how do I need to set captureConnection.videoOrientation ?? I can't understand how this need to be set.
my idea is using the phone in portrait and landscape..

Second question...
When I use Vision how do I need to set orientation in the Handler?
I tried to use a method from an apple example exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
but it is completely wrong in my case.

it only work correctly if I set the orientation as leftMirrored...

but why leftMirrored since I'm using the backCamera as input??? all the other setting give me the wrong box position.

```
    var faceLayersArray : [CAShapeLayer] = []
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        self.sessionQueue.async {
            let faceRequest = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest { req, err in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.faceLayersArray.forEach { layer in
                        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                    if let result = req.results as? [VNFaceObservation], result.count > 0 {
                        self.handleFace(observation: result)
                    } else {
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            let exifOrientation = self.exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
            guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                return
            }
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation, options: [:])
            
            do {
                
                try imageRequestHandler.perform([faceRequest])
            } catch  {
                print("Error sequance handler \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    func handleFace(observation : [VNFaceObservation]){
        for observation in observation {
            let boundBoxFace = observation.boundingBox
            let faceRectConverted = self.cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: boundBoxFace)
            let faceRectPath = CGPath(rect: faceRectConverted, transform: nil)
            
            let faceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            faceLayer.path = faceRectPath
            faceLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            faceLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
            
            faceLayersArray.append(faceLayer)
            
            self.cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.addSublayer(faceLayer)
        }
    }
    }


// from apple 
 public func exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation() -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        let curDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        let exifOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation
        
        switch curDeviceOrientation {
        case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
            exifOrientation = .left
        case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
            exifOrientation = .upMirrored
        case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
            exifOrientation = .down
        case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait:            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
            exifOrientation = .up
        default:
            exifOrientation = .up
        }
        return exifOrientation
    }
```